# Minimizing a method's coupling while still keeping it flexible

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a method that takes 2 parameters today to complete the computation. The prospects of these 2 parameters becoming 50 in the future is pretty good. Given this, what is good?

1. Write `func(int a, int b)` today. When parameters go [beyond 7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2445904/4288430), then transition to 2 or 3 below.
2. Write `func(RootOfObjectGraphWith50Fields a)` today(`RootOfObjectGraphWith50Fields` is used in other parts of the code base). This way when more parameters are needed, the method signature need not change. But this increases coupling (the method needs to know more to complete its business).
3. Write `func(InterfaceWith50Fields a)` today (with only 2 fields) and have `RootOfObjectGraphWith50Fields` implement `InterfaceWith50Fields`. This way the method signature does not have to change every time a new value is required to complete the computation. The method is not coupled to the entire `RootOfObjectGraphWith50Fields` but only to those fields that it is interested in (expressed in `InterfaceWith50Fields`).

Besides recommendations, I appreciate pointers to basic design principles behind the recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually going to recommend *both* options 1 and 3.  I recommend the first option because if your current requirement is that the method take 2 parameters, then `func(int a, int b)` is completely appropriate, at least right now.  If later on this method would require 50 parameters, then you can always just add an overloaded `func(InterfaceWith50Fields a)` version to the class.

Note that the third option does not offer very much over the second one other than that it avoids having to change the method signature.  As the POJO you are passing in really only exists to wrap 50 fields of various types, the relevant methods/behaviors in any implementing class here would be the getters.  As interfaces typically don't know anything about the data which their implementing classes would have, you might still have to rewrite some code as you upgrade from 50 to say 51 parameters.