# Is it better to create methods with a long list of parameters or wrap the parameters into an object?

Tags: c#, refactoring

Is it better(what is the best practice) to create methods with a long list of parameters or wrap the parameters into an object?

I mean lets say i have a Client data type with a long list of properties and i want to update all the properties at once. is it better to do something like

```
public int Update(int id, string name, string surname, string streetAddress, string streetAddress2, string postcode, string town, string city, string nationality, string age, string gender,string job)
{  }
```

or wrap all the properties in a object and do something like

```
public int Update(Client client)
{  }
```

thanks

Comment: use the second approach. The minute you write a call to Update, you won't remember by heart what each parameter was. IntelliSense may help, but still, it's terrible when trying to understand your code when glancing over it.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439574/whats-the-best-way-to-refactor-a-method-that-has-too-many-6-parameters

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In his book [Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672), Martin Fowler explicitly calls out long parameter lists as a **code smell** and suggest refactoring such methods to use a **Parameter Object**.

A variation is to identify how those many parameters group themselves, and create more than one Parameter Object that represent each such group.

The advantage of a Parameter Object is that the **code becomes more readable** when you can give the Parameter Object a **communicative name**. It may turn out that the Parameter Object represents a real **Domain Concept**, and the next thing you can do is to start moving **behavior** into it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is better to use an object.  If you search Stack Overflow there are numerous other posts regarding this subject

Answer (score 0):

You should normally use an object. Usually when you have a large number of parameters on a method those parameters are describing a particular "state".  Your example code points out exactly what i mean.