# Is there a better way to pass parameters in a jquery Ajax post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

As the title implies I'm looking for a better way to pass data parameters in jquery. I'm relatively new to jquery and do most of my Ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", city: "Boston" });
```

It's ok if I'm passing a couple of parameters but once it gets to more than five it gets a bit ugly. Is there a better way?

Thanks David

Comment: Seems fine to me, why does it get ugly passing an object? You could create the object outside the $.ajax function if that makes you happier ?

Comment: Hi Adeneo, yeah as Buzinas states below creating the object outside of the call was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer, you can create this object before calling your AJAX method:

```
var myParams = {};
myParams.name = "John";
myParams.city = "Boston";
// (...)

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: myParams
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .serialize()

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : $('YOUR_FORM').serialize() 
}
```

Read more about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I think you are missing a `{`

If you have too many parameters you should consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439574/whats-the-best-way-to-refactor-a-method-that-has-too-many-6-parameters). If it is a form you can serialize as already suggested. If you just want to keep it out of the ajax call you can do:

```
var info = {
    name: "John", city: "Boston"
};

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: info});
```