# How to specify fields as params for function C#?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have one `[Operation Contract]` where described function which registers a new user in WCF Service:

```
[OperationContract]
boolean Register(string name, string password);
```

This function accepts two parameters `name` and `password` of user.
How I can extend these parameters in the future, for example If I want to add second name for register function or more parameters?

I can do the following:

```
boolean Register(string name, string password, string secondName);
```

But if params are more 20?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind breaking the contract for the operation that you want to change, you could combine some of the (more than 20) parameters into a class.

This is generally good practice when writing methods that have a lot of parameters (see also [What's the best way to refactor a method that has too many (6+) parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439574/whats-the-best-way-to-refactor-a-method-that-has-too-many-6-parameters)).

You may probably need to add a `[DataContract]` attribute to that class then, though, if you want to use it in WCF calls.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `params` keyword, you can specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments.
like-

`boolean Register(params string[] list);`