# Refactoring class with a giant amount of optional but necessary parameters

Tags: c#

First: I'm not good at explaining this, as I'm rather new to C#, so apologies for any misconceptions in advance.

I am creating a testcase for some sort of wizard (a UI), a wizard which creates a new document based on criteria given to the wizard via user input.

The thing is, there's over thirty things a user can input in this wizard over the course of its various steps. So, for now, to get my testcase at least working, I've created one class with thirty parameters, of which only two are really always going to be required. All other parameters are Optional.

```
public Class DocumentParameters
{
public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
public string Parameter2 { get; set; }
etc
public string Parameter30 { get; set; }
public DocumentParameters(string parameter1, string parameter2, etc etc, [Optional]string parameter30)
{
Parameter1 = parameter1
Parameter2 = parameter2
etc
Parameter30 = parameter30
}
}
```

Then in my testcase itself, I call this Class as follows:

```
.AddNewDocumentation(new DocumentParameters("Outgoing", "Based on a template", etc etc, "ExtraComment");
```

Now, I don't have that many objections against having so many parameters, I know that there's going to be at least one scenario for each of the optional parameters.

My main issue with my approach is that it just becomes a hassle when I just want to test one of the middle parameters. Because of the way I wrote my testcase, I believe I'm obliged to test it like this:

```
.AddNewDocumentation(new DocumentParameters("Outgoing", "Fax", "Based on a template", null, null, null, null, null, 
null, null, null, null, "theParameterThatIWantToTest");
```

I'm wondering if there isn't a way where you basically can say:

```
Parameter1 = "thisValue", Parameter2 = "thisValue", Parameter16 = "thatValue"
```

and whatever parameters I don't mention, stays null. Is such a thing possible? I really don't care if I have to completely rewrite my DocumentParameters class in order to achieve it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments

Comment: Also take a look at Object Initializers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers. You can have a constructor with just your 2 required arguments and use object initializer syntax for the rest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to refactor a method that has too many (6+) parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439574/whats-the-best-way-to-refactor-a-method-that-has-too-many-6-parameters)

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring the parameters as optional, like in the following example:

```
public void DoSomething(String One = "", String Two = "", String Three ="")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(One);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Two);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Three);
    }
```

And this is how to call the procedure:

```
DoSomething(One: "Something", Three: "SomethingElse");
```

Also, beware of, all optional parameters must be declared after all required parameters, and there are no required parameters between the optional parameters.

Comment: Huh! Thanks, I've never tried it that way!
However, when I type it like this:

.AddNewDocumentation(DocumentParameters(parameter1: "x", parameter2: "y", parameter15: "z", parameter16: "zz")

Then he returns a CS8323 (Named argument 'parameter15' is used out-of-position but is followed by an unnamed argument.)

How would I solve that?

Comment: I forgot to tell you that optional parameters must be at the end of the parameter list of the procedure when they are declared, and that there are no required parameters between the optional parameters!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, in that case you should define also a construcotr with just two paramteres that are required:

```
public DocumentParameters(string parameter1, string parameter2)
{
    Parameter1 = parameter1;
    Parameter2 = parameter2;
}
```

And when testing you could just do:

```
var docParams = new DocumentParameters("parameter1", "parameter2") { Parameter17 = "parameter17" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options can be made:

1. Remove your constructor and use an initializer:

`var parameters = new DocumentParameters
{
   Parameter1 = "Outgoing",
   Parameter2 = "Based on a template"
};

 // The rest of the parameters will be with default values.
.AddNewDocumentation (parameters);



Add constructor overload for required parameters:


public class DocumentParameters
{
   public string Parameter1 {get; set; }
   public string Parameter2 {get; set; }
   etc

   public DocumentParameters (string parameter1, string parameter2)
   {
      Parameter1 = parameter1
      Parameter2 = parameter2
   }

   public DocumentParameters (string parameter1, string parameter2, etc)
   {
      Parameter1 = parameter1
      Parameter2 = parameter2
      etc
   }
}

// The rest of the parameters will be with default values.
.AddNewDocumentation (new DocumentParameters ("Outgoing", "Fax"));


3.Make parameters optional and use with names:

public class DocumentParameters
{
   public string Parameter1 {get; set; }
   public string Parameter2 {get; set; }
   public string Parameter3 {get; set; }
   etc

   public DocumentParameters (
   string parameter1, 
   string parameter2,
   string parameter3 = null, 
   etc = null)
   {
      Parameter1 = parameter1
      Parameter2 = parameter2
      Parameter3 = parameter3
      etc
   }
}

.AddNewDocumentation (new DocumentParameters ("Outgoing", "Fax"));

.AddNewDocumentation (new DocumentParameters ("Outgoing", "Fax",
parameter3: "Based on a template"));

.AddNewDocumentation (new DocumentParameters ("Outgoing", "Fax",
parameter30: "theParameterThatIWantToTest"));`

Answer (score 0):

If you wizard has a reasonable number of discrete configuration types (let's say "Animals", "Automobiles" and "GeologicFeatures"), you could create an interface, say:

```
public interface IWizardConfiguration {
    void ConfigureDocumentParametersInstance (DocumentParameters objectToConfigure);
}
```

And then have classes like `AnimalConfiguration`, `AutomobileConfiguration` and `GeologicFeature` configuration.

Add a constructor to your `DocumentParameters` that takes just an `IWizardConfiguration` parameter.  Your users can now create something like an `AnimalConfiguration` instance, providing just the parameters that are need to configure an animal.  The `AnimalConfiguration` instance is then responsible for configuring all the many parameters of a `DocumentParameters` instance:

```
public DocumentParameters(IWizardConfiguration configuration) {
    configuration.ConfigureDocumentParametersInstance (this);
}
```

This may not suit your needs, but it might be useful.